# Cosa significa "al pulito" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *I ventitré giorni della città di Alba*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> La repubblica stabilí un fronte di non piú di mezzo chilometro, disteso tra un pescheto e un arenile, e cercò di far forza nel punto migliore per il guado, immediatamente a valle del ponte bombardato dagli inglesi. Ma i partigiani concentrarono le mitraglie e quando quelli si presentarono **al pulito**, fecero una salva che li ricacciò tutti nei cespugli.

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "al pulito" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "pulito" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato nulla che possa avere senso in questo contesto.

Comment: A orecchio, lo parafraserei con “allo scoperto”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al pulito significa nel prato, in una radura senza alberi o cespugli che potessero proteggere i repubblicani dal fuoco partigiano.

Come correttamente sottolineato da @DaG *al pulito* nel contesto da te citato potrebbe essere sostituito da *allo scoperto*.

Answer (score 3):

Per "pulito" intenderei in questo contesto uno spazio aperto, privo di coperture e protezioni.

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!